# pyqt5 how to open new window and reopen old

Tags: python, python-3.x, menu, pyqt5

> Hello
>   I do not know what to do, the window (**register.py**) opens very well from **login.py**, but the window (**login.py**) does not not open since **register.py**.

What to do?

> register.py

https://hastebin.com/oyoxoyemak.rb

> login.py

https://hastebin.com/tanuhigome.rb

[error code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bUpmX.png)

error code if i remove

```
        screen = app.primaryScreen()
        size = screen.size()
        print('Size: %d x %d' % (size.width(), size.height()))
        rect = screen.availableGeometry()
        print('Available: %d x %d' % (rect.width(), rect.height()))
        self.window.move((rect.width() / 2) - 230, (rect.height() / 2) - 230)
```

[error code 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KsMdE.png)

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the guidelines on [how to ask questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), take some time to create a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) which has to be runnable without too much efforts, and remember to avoid external services for code, as they might become unavailable sometimes, making it impossible to access it to future users which might be looking for a solution to a similar problem or be able to assist you more.

Answer (score 0):

Both issues are related to the scope.
`app` is a local variable in both scripts, which exists only in the scope of the script that is running (the `if __name__ == "__main__":` line).
So, if you run login.py, `app` is available in its scope, but if you run register.py `app` exists only for it, but not in the login.py scope (since it was never created "there").

Since primaryScreen is a static function, you don't need a reference to the application instance (which you could get through `QtWidgets.QApplication.instance()`, anyway):

Just change that line to:

```
    screen = QtWidgets.QApplication.primaryScreen()
```

In the second issue, the problem is similar: since you're running login.py, `MainWindow_Register` is never declared in register.py.

I have not a "simple" solution for that, as your approach is a bit confused.
First of all, it seems like you're trying to implent your program starting from the output of pyuic, and if that's the case you should really avoid it: write your own code and use the pyuic generated files as suggested in the [documentation](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/designer.html).
Then, whenever you have to face multiple related windows, it's better to avoid calling themselves "recursively", and use a single window (or better, a separate object, even a subclass of QApplication) as a "manager". This will make everything easier programmatically, avoiding redundant code, while decreasing the possibility of bugs.

In your case, you should probably always use the login window as a "starting point", then show the register one whenever necessary.